# How to import noise model from IBM qiskit real device?

Tags: qiskit, simulation, noise

I am trying to import the noise model of an IBM 'large' device. I don't have access to the devices with more than 7 qubits so it doesn't allow me to import the backend and then do

`noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)`

Is there another way I can import the noise model from those devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qiskit includes calibration data for many IBM Quantum devices, they are called `Fake*` and you can find them in `qiskit.providers.fake_provider`. For example, for `ibmq_kolkata` (27 qubits):

```
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeKolkata
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel

backend = FakeKolkata()
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)
```